# how to write php script for saving admin configurations in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, admin, configuration

I want to write a script that saves the admin configuration every time when I ***`deploy/upgrade`.***

***For example, I need to have a PHP script for saving this admin configuration.***

```
 Admin panel-> Stores-> Configuration-> Catalog-> Inventory-> Display out of stock products -> YES
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write anything. Configs can be updated via console commands

`bin/magento config:set [--scope="..."] [--scope-code="..."] [-le | --lock-env] [-lc | --lock-config] path value`

For example

`bin/magento config:set web/unsecure/base_url http://example.com/`

Or using magerun

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

`n98-magerun2.phar config:store:set [--scope[="..."]] [--scope-id[="..."]] [--encrypt] path value`

For example

`n98-magerun2.phar config:store:set dev/js/merge_files 1`